# How to open IE8 with factory settings?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible to open IE8 with factory settings without actually resetting the settings? There is a way to disable plugin using `iexplore.ext -extoff`. Most of the linux programs allow some means to load the program without loading the settings.

Answer (score 1):

While Internet Explorer supports several [command-line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx), there is not one that loads it using factory settings.  (An older blog post from the IE Dev team blog discusses the [reset settings feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/06/12/628499.aspx), but doesn't mention a way to do so temporarily.)

As far as `-extoff` goes, I'm not sure what you're asking.  By definition, it disables all plugins.  It doesn't provide a way to selectively disable individual plugins. (You have to [do that manually](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/07/25/678113.aspx).)

(I have noticed that some addons become more manageable if you uninstall them and re-install them, but that's anectodal at best.)

If there's a specific add-on you're having trouble with, it might be possible to provide more specific advice.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Disabling all addons is OK for us because we were just testing if an issue is caused by ANY of the plugins . However the next logical step is to find the plugin but we haven't reached that far yet. Thanks for the pointer.